# Cylindrical coordinates, confusing example

Tags: calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

I wish to calculate $\iiint_{E}z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dV$ where $E$ is the domain trapped between the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$ and the planes $y=0$, $z=0$, $z=a$

In the answers sheet, the professor transforms the problem to cylinderical coordinates and writes:

$x = r\cos \theta$, $y = r\sin \theta$, $z=z$, and the limits are $0<z<a$, $0<\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $0<r<2\cos \theta$

I'm confused as to why $r < 2\cos \theta$. Shouldn't it be $r < \sqrt{2\cos \theta}$?

Comment: The plane $y=0$ slices the cylinder in half. Which half is part of $E$? The part where $y > 0$?

Comment: Your can check the correctness of the bounds on $r$ by first plotting the Cartesian form and overlaying the polar form. Note that $r$ is a function of $\theta$. You can find that relation by plugging in $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ in $x^2+y^2 = 2x$.

Answer (score 2):

The points within the cylinder satisfy $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x$.
With the appropriate coordinate substitutions,
$$r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2 \sin^2\theta \leq 2r\cos\theta, \implies r^2\leq 2r\cos\theta, \implies r\leq 2\cos\theta. $$
Then, to solve the integral, you need to expand $dV = rdrd\theta dz$ (don't forget the Jacobian $r$ factor!), make the appropriate substitutions within the integrand, and set the bounds $r \in [0,2\cos\theta]$, $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$, $z \in [0,a]$. Can you go on from here?